# Pure Android Download

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it that Android still can’t be installed as regular OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20364/why-is-it-that-android-still-cant-be-installed-as-regular-os)

I have been looking around, and was wondering is it not possible to download android 4.2 out of the box (non-phone specific)?

I thought that I could just get Google's version of Android and slap it on my phone, but their is no Android rom that I can download (At least not that I can find).

Comment: Unless you have a Nexus device this won't work out-of-the-box anyway. The drivers for most phone components are proprietary, and you'd have to re-write them all. Your best bet for something like this is usually a third-party ROM like [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.org).

Comment: Related: [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29394), [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364)