# How to nexusify galaxy s4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, nexus-4, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I was an iPhone user for long time and recently switched to Samsung Galaxy S4 which is supposed to be the best android phone out there (at least best samsung phone). I like to try the real android the Google experience. What kind of apps, widgets, launcher, ... should I install?

Comment: Also [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/flash-a-smartphone-with-vanilla-android-rom). We don't do "what do you suggest" style questions, but the two linked questions have other resources.