# How to install Stock Android on Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 s7270

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, stock-android

I was wondering if it is possible to install the official stock android operating system from google without the customization of the manufacturer like Touch Wiz on Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 s7270, is there a way to do this

Comment: Maybe XDA might have the answer for you on how to mod your device and install AOSP on it, you are rooted? You have custom recovery on it?

Comment: No do you know any tutorial for this ? How can I install stock android on galaxy ace 3 ?

Comment: Seems that its recent and there's no interest in custom ROM's for the device in question... [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2530715) am not sure as really its the community that dictates the popularity of devices, could try [Modaco](http://modaco.co.uk)?

Comment: @DanHulme Do you read english how this could be possible of a duplicate I am asking for stock android released by google for mobiles not for a custom ROM

Comment: Google doesn't release stock Android for other manufacturers' devices (except for Google Play Edition phones, which are still in partnership with the manufacturer). If you want a close-to-AOSP build for your phone, a custom ROM is the way to achieve that.

Comment: [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/flash-a-smartphone-with-vanilla-android-rom) might be a better duplicate (IMHO)