# How dependent are stylus devices on software?

Tags: stylus

I am considering acquiring a tablet or phablet with integrated stylus. One of the first things I expect to do with is flashing the latest vanilla Android release. That done, is the stylus expected to work properly? Can I then install alternative note taking programmes (e.g. [Quill](https://code.google.com/p/android-quill/))? Or is the stylus functionality fully dependent on vendor software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, you can't install "vanilla Android" on a non-Nexus device. See [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/flash-a-smartphone-with-vanilla-android-rom) for more. The closest you can get is a custom ROM that was originally based on AOSP and then ported to your device, such as Cyanogenmod.

The custom ROM's documentation should say whether it has the drivers for the stylus, and if so, it'll work just like a more precise touchscreen. You still won't get any special stylus features (like extra buttons or pressure-sensitivity) in this case, though. There's no standard Android interface for such features, so they rely on the vendor's proprietary library and interfaces for apps to support them. Again, you should check the custom ROM's documentation to find out how much is supported.

Comment: I just wanted to add this, for what it is worth as a comment: as Dan says here there isn't vanilla Android for a device, and from my own experience on a lot of devices these ROMs rarely work as well as stock. Unless it is based on something like Touchwiz (Samsung) with S-Pen (Samsung sylus) support it won't work as you think it will. Porting these things *can* be a nightmare and most ROMs that aren't based on the Stock ROM won't. I have an S4 here with a very close to Stock ROM and a Nexus 5, the Nexus makes the S4 look like a potato it's so much smoother. You always lose out somewhere.